# JWrapper doesn't auto-update when launched from URL

Tags: jwrapper

I have a JWrapper app that registers itself as a URL handler, as [described in the docs](http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-url-handling.html).

```
String vappName = JWApp.getMyVirtualApp().getUserVisibleName();
JWMacOS.registerURLSchemeForVirtualApp("myapp", vappName);
```

The URL handler part works great, and my app launches just fine when I click on a `myapp://foo/bar` link.

The same app is also configured in the **jwrapper.xml** file to check for [automatic updates](http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-automatic-updates.html), and that's where things get interesting. When I launch the app from the dock (by clicking on the icon), the app checks for updates and can successfully update itself, as expected. However, if the app is launched via a URL, the update check is skipped.

No matter what I do, I cannot get the app to automatically update if it is launched from a URL. I can launch it via URL several times in a row, and it never updates, but it will update just fine the next time I launch it via the dock icon.

Is there a way to get JWrapper to check for updates when launched from a URL? I have tried setting `MatchClientVersionToServerVersion` to both `true` and `false`, but it doesn't seem to help. Perhaps I am registering the URL handler incorrectly?

Updated: Just wanted to note that I implemented the **JWrapperUpdateApp** install screen for debugging. It pops up a little JOptionPane alert letting me know that it is checking for updates. I see that alert as expected when I start the app from the dock, but never when I launch it from a URL.